# docker container as router to route traffic to all docker containers

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I am working on a project which requires me to have 3 containers on 3 different docker networks and add another docker container in front of these 3 as a router. (Trying to simulate a network and packet capture at each scope). How do I set up the router container which is aware of all the other 3 networks and just sits there and routes traffic along. I looked around, but have no luck in getting through this. Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried setting up a router container with just ubuntu and use that as the net by using `--net=router-container` but that shares the network the router container is on with other containers giving them the same IP, which is not essentially what I would need. A setup that I was looking for would be something like this.

[image]

Comment: You might take a look at [Traefik](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/).

Comment: @f_puras Thanks for that, I believe Traefik is for https traffic. Does it support all ports and protocols?

Comment: As far as I understand it, you can route about anything with Traefik - e.g. TCP: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#configuring-tcp-routers